# how do I use the value resolved from a Data-Binding expression in an in-line if-else statement in Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I get a good string value from the following Data-Binding expression in a ASP.NET Web Forms ascx control:

```
<%# ((MyCompany.CoreLib.Main.ChallengeQuestion)Container.DataItem).AnswerType %>
```

I want to do something like:

```
<EditItemTemplate>

<% if (%>
    <%# ((MyCompany.CoreLib.Main.ChallengeQuestion)Container.DataItem).AnswerType %>
<% == "DateTime") { %>
Show this text
<% ; } else { %>
Show this other text
<% ; } %>

<EditItemTemplate>
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: You could use the `OnDataBinding` event per your control to perform any logic need prior to populating your data at a line level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible but you could define a method on the code behind and use it on the aspx

**CODE BEHIND**

```
public string GetAnswerTypeText(MyCompany.CoreLib.Main.ChallengeQuestion challengeQuestion)
{
   if (challengeQuestion.AnswerType.Equals("DateTime"))
   {
       return "some text";
   }
   else
   {
       return "some other text";
   }
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<%# GetAnswerTypeText((MyCompany.CoreLib.Main.ChallengeQuestion)Container.DataItem) %>
```

Comment: This works, but I failed to mention that the text I want to return is markup like: return "<asp:TextBox ID='AnswerTextConfirm' TextMode='Password' runat='server'></ asp:TextBox>";.  For some reason, the tags render as hidden/invisible, so they do not show up on the page.  Any tips on that part?